# Trying to add in app email of a text field

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

It seems to be working but I am getting a compile warning inside of my showEmailModalView method on the line: picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;  It says "Passing MyAppViewController *const_strong to parameter of incompatible type 'id"  If anyone can help with this I will appreciate it.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
    { 
        switch (result)
        {
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                break;

            default:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Sending Failed - Unknown Error :-("
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];

            }

                break;
        }
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

-(void) showEmailModalView {

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    backUpTape = tapeDisplay.text;
    [picker setMessageBody:backUpTape isHTML:NO]; 

    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteboard setValue:tapeDisplay.text forPasteboardType:@"public.utf8-plain-text"];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 2)
        [self showEmailModalView];

}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(tapeDisplay.frame, location)) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Copy"
                                                        message: @""
                                                       delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles: @"Copy", @"email", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like somebody isn't conforming to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.  Put it in a pair of these `<>` in the .h file and see if the error goes away when you build and run again.

Comment: It should go something like @interface Class : MyClass <DELEGATES> {

Comment: I added (id) before self    picker.mailComposeDelegate = (id) self;  and it now compiles with no warnings.  Acceptable?

Comment: NO!  Not unless you are the DELEGATE.  You want the delegate methods to be called, right? Because, sure it silences the warnings, but it won't call a darn thing.

Comment: The strange thing is that it does dismiss the picker when the mail is sent or cancelled as I have it.  So confused.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I placed the delegate improperly in my .h file.

Comment: Well sure it dismisses, but delegates are set so that delegate METHODS are called.  If you don't need the delegate methods, don't use the delegate!